# saving processed data in django model?

Tags: python, django

I'm working in a project where users upload a photo and it will be processed on a server then served back and saved to be shown as some sort of comparison.
this is my model for the uploaded images

```
class AnalysesImages(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(user,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to = user_directory_path ,
                                            verbose_name = 'Image')
```

i have the idea of creating another model for the processed data(image) but how i should retrieve it? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way. If the process would be done with the same language (in my case is python) you can make a function where it simply call the image and process it and be saved as another field in the model like:

```
   class AnalysesImages(models.Model):
     patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     pre_analysed = models.ImageField(upload_to = user_directory_path ,
                                            verbose_name = 'Image')
     analysed = models.ImageField(upload_to=analyses_directory_path,
                                            verbose_name='analysed Image')

# function for analysing the images
    def analyse_image(self):
        return self.pre_analysed

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.analysed = self.analyse_image()
        super(AnalysesImages, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```